# How to find line parallel to direction vector and passing through a specific point?

Tags: vectors, 3d

I am give the point $(1,0,-3)$ and the vector $2i-4j+5k$

Find the equation of the line parallel to vector and passing through point $(1,0,-3)$

Could one use the fact that the dot product between the line and the vector?

Please give me some direction as where to go for this question. I am so lost

Comment: $L\equiv P+t\mathbf{v}$ should do the trick.

Comment: So in this case P would be the point, and v would be the vector and then I would have to solve for constant t which would make v be the same as P? @Jp McCarthy

Comment: No... different values of $t$ give you different points along the line. $P+t\mathbf{v}$ is the answer. Draw a picture.

Answer (score 5):

In general, we know that the equation of the line passing through the point $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ & parallel to the vector $(ai+bj+ck)$ is given as $$\frac{x-x_1}{a}=\frac{y-y_1}{b}=\frac{z-z_1}{c}$$

Hence, the equation of the line passing through the point $(1, 0, -3)$ & parallel to the vector $(2i-4j+5k)$ is given as $$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{y-0}{-4}=\frac{z-(-3)}{5}$$ 
$$\frac{x-1}{2}=\frac{-y}{4}=\frac{z+3}{5}$$ It can also be represented as

> $$r(t)=(1, 0, -3)+t(2, -4, 5)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x-x_0}{v_x} = \frac{y-y_0}{v_y} = \frac{z-z_0}{v_z}$$
This is line equation in 3D, where $v$ is your vector and $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is the given point.