# How to find the normal line of $z = 4x^2 + y^2 - 78$ at $(2,1,-61)$?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, partial-derivative

> How do I find the normal line of $z = 4x^2 + y^2 - 78$ at $(2,1,-61)$?

I have found that the tangent plane is $z-16x-2y=95$ but I don't know how to find the normal line.

The answer is:
$$\frac{2 - x}{16} = \frac{1 - y}{2} = z + 61$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the tangent plane, the vector normal to plane will also be normal to the surface.

We know normal vector to plane of equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is $n=<a,b,c>$.

We also know a point on the line.

Hence we can form a equation,

$x = 2 -16t $

$y = 1 -2t$

$z = -61 + t$

This is same as your equation.

*([For forming line equation with a given direction vector and given piont see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976812/how-to-find-line-parallel-to-direction-vector-and-passing-through-a-specific-poi))*